# Using Ajax to fetch data from an External API and data from a local excel spreadsheet

Tags: javascript, ajax, xml, api, xmlhttprequest

Somebody please have a look at my code below, I am trying to Use Ajax to fetch data from an External API. My issue is:

1. I get an error in the console that says, `Uncaught Syntax error: Unexpected Identifier` on line 27 `document.getElementById('button')addEventListener('click', loadUsers);`. If I run this code in browser, I get a blank page.
2. Can somebody also guide on how I can transform this code using JavaScript (or any of it's libraries) to fetch data from a local excel spread sheet, in such a way that, if my excel sheet has two fields, i.e. `Name` and `ID`, the user is required to enter just a matching ID and I thereafter his `Name` and `ID` is displayed somewhere on the page. Your efforts will be highly appreciated.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title> Using Ajax 3 to fetch data from an External API</title>
    <style>
        .user{
            display: flex;
            background:#f4f4f4;
            padding:10px;
            margin-bottom:10px;
        }
        
        .user ul{
            list-style: none;
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<button id="button"> Load Github Users</button>
<br /> <br/>
<h1>Github Users</h1>
<div id="users"></div>

<script>
document.getElementById('button')addEventListener('click', loadUsers);

//Load Github users

function loadUsers(){
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('GET', 'https://api.github.com/users', true);
    
    xhr.onload = function(){
        if(this.status == 200){
            var users =JSON.parse(this.responseText);
            console.log(users);
            var  output = ' ';
            for(var i in users){
                output +=
                '<dic class="user">' + 
                '<img src="'+users[i].avatar_url+'" width="70"
                height="70">' +
                '<ul>' +
                '<li> ID: '+users[i].id+'</li>' +
                '<li>Login: '+users[i].login+'<li>' +
                '</ul>'
                '</div>';
            }
            
            [document.getElementById('users').innerHTML = output;
        }
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You're missing dot between getElementById('button').addEventListener().

Comment: As for loading data from a local spreadsheet: you should use a proper backend and database instead. You can in theory manually pick the excel file using an `<input type="file">` then open it with a suitable library and extract data but that is not a suitable solution for managing users and their IDs.

Comment: I fixed the dot and a couple of bugs but the functionality still doesn't work and console shows no error.